# An explicit basis of space of modular forms $M_5(\Gamma_0(11),(\frac{\bullet}{11}))$

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, theta-functions

I want to find a basis of space of modular forms in $M_5\left(\Gamma_0(11),\left(\frac{\bullet}{11}\right)\right)$, which is of dimension $5$. **Additionally, I want the basis to have explicit forms.**

Here is my approach:

Using $\eta$-quotient, I found two basis elements as follows

$$\frac{\eta^{11}(z)}{\eta(11z)}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\eta^{11}(11z)}{\eta(z)}.$$

Using the $U$ operator, I constructed the remaining basis elements

$$\frac{\eta^{11}(z)}{\eta(11z)}\ |\ U(11),\quad\frac{\eta^{11}(11z)}{\eta(z)}\ |\ U(11),\quad\frac{\eta^{11}(11z)}{\eta(z)}\ |\ U(121),$$

where $\sum a(n)q^n\ |\ u(m):=\sum a(mn)q^n$.

However, the basis I want looks like

$$\frac{\eta^{11}(z)}{\eta(11z)}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\eta^{11}(11z)}{\eta(z)},$$

which have **explicit forms**

$$\frac{\eta^{11}(z)}{\eta(11z)}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^n)^{11}}{1-q^{11n}}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\eta^{11}(11z)}{\eta(z)}=q^5\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^{11n})^{11}}{1-q^n}.$$

Maybe we can use Eisenstein series or theta functions to construct such modular forms, but I am not familiar with those theories.

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: Most spaces of modular forms don't have bases in this kind of "explicit" shape. It sounds to me like you already have as good an answer to your question as you can reasonably hope for!

Comment: @DavidLoeffler.  I think you are right. If the level of spaces of modular forms is divisible by large primes, it is hard to construct such ''explicit'' forms.